# Usar array_diff con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy intentado usar la función `array_diff` de PHP, el problema es que intento hacerlo con dos variables que tengo en mi función.

```
$var1 = Model::all();
$var2 = Model1::all();

// Trato de eliminar valores repetidos
$var3 = array_diff($var1, $var2);
```

El error que me lanza es:

> array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array

Comment: tu variable $var1 no es arreglo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema ya lo mencionaron , `$var1` y `$var2` **no son arrays** , es lo que espera `array_diff()` , Sí esta empleando `Laravel` existen [métodos](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections)  de la clase `Illuminate\Support\Collection` para trabajar con colecciones que es  lo que retorna `All()`.

Para su ejemplo sería emplear [$coleccion->diff($coleccion2)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-diff)

```
$var1 = Model::all();
$var2 = Model1::all();
$diff = $var1->diff($var2);
dd($diff->all());
```

Comment: Me sale un error, "Call to undefined method stdClass::getKey()"

Comment: Tengo la siguiente consulta: http://prntscr.com/h6w77y

Comment: @MarcialCahuayaTarqui eso es porque emplea `Eloquet`que retorna una colección de su Modelo , y el generador de consultas para la otra consulta lo cuál retorna una colección de objetos `StdClass`. Debe emplear `Eloquent` para ambos casos.

Answer (score 0):

### El problema

El mensaje de error es muy claro:

> array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array

Te está diciendo que el argumento 1, o sea, `$var1` no es un array.

Como es evidente, `array_diff` debe recibir en parámetro dos arrays, como muestra el [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff.php):

```
array_diff ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )
```

Es evidente que **la llamada a `Model::all();` no está devolviendo un array realmente**.

Para probarlo basta con ejecutar esta línea de código:

```
var_dump ($var);
```

La salida por pantalla te dirá lo que es `$var`, si fuese un array deberías ver algo más o menos así:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Si no dice `array` al principio del todo no es un array...

---

### La solución

Deberás revisar el método `all`  de la clase `Model`, verificando que dicho método retorna un array.

Comment: @MarcialCahuayaTarqui Ya, pero si cualquiera de los dos valores que pasas a `array_diff` no es un array no funcionará. Puedes probar creando tú mismo el array y verás que funciona: `$var1=array(1,2,3); $var2=array(1,2); $var3=array_diff($var1, $var2);`. Luego haces `print_r($var3);`  y te imprimirá el resultado.

Comment: Si, eso se claramente, lo que estoy retornando son objetos de Laravel, consultas eloquent. Estoy tratando de hacer otras formas para que me elimine los valores de 2 foreach iguales.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner en la pregunta el resultado de `var_dump($var1);`  y `var_dump($var2);` para ver qué es lo que estás obteniendo en esas variables?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te está devolviendo es un Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection. Este objeto tiene a su vez varios métodos para operar con una colección de elementos.

En tu caso, te informo que uno de esos métodos es toArray(), que te devuelve un array.

Puedes probar con

$var1 = Modelo::all()->toArray();

Para ver qué te devuelve un array, lo que tendrás que averiguar es si te vale para tu array_diff, porque muy probablemente te devuelva un array de objetos de tu entidad... Puede que el array_diff no te devuelva lo que esperas...

Comment: Revisa los métodos del collection.... Seguro que hay alguno para obtener los no repetidos, o incluso alguno para buscar los Diff quebuscas

Answer (score 0):

Logré solucionar convirtiendo el objeto en arrays

```
$var1 = array();
foreach ($var1 as $key => $value) {
   $var1[] = $value->id;
}

$var2 = array();
foreach ($var2 as $key => $value) {
   $var2[] = $value->id;
}

$var3 = array_diff($var1, $var2);
```